# Why do I get error on flurry when trying to compile to release on Android?

Tags: android, flurry

when I tried to compile to release using `./gradlew assembleRelease`
, I got these error. I didn't signed it yet, but according to http://developer.android.com/tools/building/building-cmdline.html, I can signed it later.

```
Warning: com.flurry.sdk.hn: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient
Warning: com.flurry.sdk.hn: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info
Warning: com.flurry.sdk.hn: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient
Warning: com.flurry.sdk.hn: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info
Warning: com.flurry.sdk.hn: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info
Warning: com.flurry.sdk.hn: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info
Warning: com.flurry.sdk.hn: can't find referenced class com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient$Info
Warning: com.flurry.sdk.kg: can't find referenced class com.flurry.sdk.i
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

from [Flurry integrations with Android App gives an error "Could not find class 'com.flurry.sdk.i', referenced from method com.flurry.sdk.hu.a"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29094916/flurry-integrations-with-android-app-gives-an-error-could-not-find-class-com-f), if you don't care about FlurryAds, you can ignore it.

in your `app/proguard-rules.pro`, insert these lines

```
-dontwarn com.google.android.gms.ads.identifier.AdvertisingIdClient**
-dontwarn com.flurry.sdk.i
```